# Android create graph from data in TextView

Tags: android, android-graphview

I am creating a pulse rate monitoring app. I receive the realtime pulse data which is displayed in a textview. How can I create a realtime graph from the data which is shown in Textview? I am using android-graphview for creating the graph.

Thanks

Comment: I have tried using addTextchangedListener() and created an array of text received in OnTextChanged. However I don't know how to implement this array in the graph. Can you please explain how to use the created array into the graph?

Answer (score 0):

There is too many library available for creating chart in Android.
1. aChartEngine
2. HelloChart
3. MPChart

I suggest you to please go through this. You will find your solution.

Comment: I checked the documentation for a few but couldn't find how to chart realtime data from textview.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing.
Use simple textwatcher to listen text data when it change and draw you graph.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing a graph is simple create a graph view in XML file of the activity. 
And than in java class use this code to create graph.

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
          new DataPoint(0, 1),
          new DataPoint(1, 5),
          new DataPoint(2, 3)
});
graph.addSeries(series);
```

You can use  `textview.addTextChangedListener()` to update the graph as new values are recieved.

Comment: I have tried using addTextchangedListener() and created an array of text received in OnTextChanged. However I don't know how to implement this array in the graph. Can you please explain how to use the created array into the graph?

Comment: How can we use Java Class's variables in DataPoint(0,1) as DataPoint(x1, y1) please help me.